# What is the best way to load balance javascript applications?

Tags: javascript

I write a lot of javascript applications and in many different circumstances the browser will become unresponsive or give a "slow script" error. Even when following best practices, initializing large data sets, complex animation, or when too many event handlers fire at once, I have to include extra setTimeouts or requestAnimationFrames around script blocks to load balance them. Seems like there should be some standard way of managing the browser load for large javascript applications.

Any ideas? It seems like there must be JS application designers thinking about this, but I can find nothing on the web or on stack.

Comment: Sorry to be cocky, but you say you write JS following best practices. I know you wrote Frame.js, which performs `for...in` loops on arrays _all the time_. That's not exactly best practice... But seriously: Yes there should be a more standard way of going about the business of large JS applications. All the same, perhaps this question fits the programmers exchange site's format better?

Comment: I posted it [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196949/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-balance-javascript-applications). PS. Wow, I'm famous enough to have haters j/k. Thanks for the note, and Frame v1 was not meant to be perforative. Version 2 will be though.

Comment: I just checked your SO profile, and clicked on your to 2 answers to see what kind of JS you write. Some people think they write good JS because they manage to force all sorts of Java patters onto the language. If you were doing things like that, I'd have had a hunch as to what is causing your JS to be so slow ;-P

Comment: Haha. I could not agree more. JS is a functional, client-side, run-time language. Very different from Java or Objective-C or anything else. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: JS can be server-side, too (he said pedantically) :P, oh, and I posted an answer to your question on programmers.stackexchange